# Get ALL strings from html

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I send get requests to different sites. In response I get HTML pages. How can I get only strings from the HTML page?
I mean all strings in general (the ones colored white in my screenshot).
[image]

I understand how I can get "div", "code", "a", and etc tags.
But I need to get all the lines that are painted white in the developer tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get all the human readable text of the HTML `<body>` you can use [`.get_text()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text), to get rid of redundant whitespaces, etc. set strip parameter and join/separate all by a single whitespace:

```
import bs4
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.text)
soup.body.get_text(' ', strip=True)
```